# Client Side Validations success message on attribute with no validations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side-validation

I'm using the [client_side_validations gem](http://goo.gl/t2M57) to validate a contact form. The gem displays error messages beside fields when they are invalid. I have also implemented a custom callback ([see the Github wiki](http://goo.gl/Ozbdi)) to display a success message beside fields when the user has filled them with valid information.

```
// Define a callback to run whenever an attribute passes validations
clientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass = function($element, callback) {
  console.log("Element passed", $element);
  // Allow clientSideValidations to do it's thing.
  callback();
  // Add a success message to give the user an ego lift.
  $element.closest('p').addClass('pass');
  $message = $('<span class="message">Great job!</span>');
  $element.after($message);
};
```

However I run into a problem when I have a field which has no validations at all

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :phone_number

  validates :name, presence: true
  # I don't need to validate the phone number in any way.
end
```

In this case, when the user tabs through the phone number field, the `pass` callback never gets run. I've tried to use the `after` callback to do this instead but I don't seem to run either.

Is there a way I can force the callbacks to run on every field in my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This just isn't the behavior of the gem. It's not possible.](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/359)